# Prove that the following inequality is true for all $m \in (0, 3)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Prove that the following inequality is true for all $m \in (0, 3)$
> $$\sqrt {{m^2} + 1}  + \sqrt {{{\left( {3 - m} \right)}^2} + 1}  \le \sqrt {\frac{{2\left( {4{m^2} - 12m - 15} \right)}}{{(m - 3)m}}}  - 1.$$

I have defined
$$f\left( m \right) = \sqrt {{m^2} + 1}  + \sqrt {{{\left( {3 - m} \right)}^2} + 1} ,g\left( m \right) = \sqrt {\frac{{2\left( {4{m^2} - 12m - 15} \right)}}{{(m - 3)m}}}  - 1.$$

but they do not make the function monotonous. The derivative of the function $h(m)=f(m)-g(m)$ is quite complicated.

Another approach is to square both sides. I have tried squaring it four times, but it is still quite complicated. I would appreciate it if you could give me some ideas to prove the inequality. Thank you!

Comment: Was this the problem, or is it a step in solving some other problem? The inequality is not tight, though close enough to not be easy. You could try to write it as a minimization problem for $f(u,v) = \sqrt{8 + \frac{30}{uv}} - \sqrt{u^2+1} - \sqrt{v^2+1}$ subject to $u + v = 3$ but the calculations are still not pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{m^2 + 1} + \sqrt{(3 - m)^2 + 1} + 1\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \sqrt{\left(\frac32 + \frac32 + 1\right)\left(\frac{m^2 + 1}{3/2} + \frac{(3 - m)^2 + 1}{3/2} + 1\right)}.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
$$
 \left(\frac32 + \frac32 + 1\right)\left(\frac{m^2 + 1}{3/2} + \frac{(3 - m)^2 + 1}{3/2} + 1\right) \le \frac{{2\left( {4{m^2} - 12m - 15} \right)}}{{(m - 3)m}}
$$
or
$$\frac{(4m^2 - 12m + 10)(3 - 2m)^2}{3m(3 - m)} \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Could you please provide me with your personal information (sending it through my personal messages is also fine)? Your solutions are excellent, and I use them, so please give me the information so that I can properly cite them. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Math_fun2006 It is not a difficult problem. So, it is not necessary to cite something.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer.

Define

$$f(m) = \sqrt {\frac{{2\left( {4{m^2} - 12m - 15} \right)}}{{(m - 3)m}}}  - 1 - \sqrt {{m^2} + 1}  - \sqrt {{{\left( {3 - m} \right)}^2} + 1}$$

We want to prove $f(m)\geq 0$ for $m\in (0,3)$ to establish your inequality. Verify that $f(m)=f(3-m)$, indeed $4m^2-12m = 4m(m-3)$. So $f(m)=f(3-m)$ and $f$ is symmetric on $1.5$.

Now consider the Taylor series terms of $f$ with center $1.5$. $f$ is symetric on $1.5$, so all the terms of the expansion are even terms. So we have

$$f(m) = \left(-\sqrt{13}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}-1\right)+\left(\frac{10}{9 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{8}{13 \sqrt{13}}\right) \left(m-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+...\\ \approx 0.0132509 + 0.470823 (m-1.5)^2 + 0.208245 (m-1.5)^4 +0.0905318 (m-1.5)^6$$

Notice that the coefficients are positive and only for even powers (because $f$ is symetric on $1.5$). If indeed all coefficients are positive, then $f$ is minimized at $1.5$. Showing this is difficult because there is no clean closed form. Here is a graphical plot of the function around $m=1.5$.

[image: Plot of function around minimizer]

Comment: I've verified that the coefficients are positive up to the $100$th term. I don't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The given inequality is
$$\sqrt{m^2 + 1} + \sqrt{(3-m)^2 + 1} \leq \sqrt{\frac{2(4m^2 - 12m -15}{(m-3)m}} \ \text{where,} \ m \in [0, 3]$$

I took the following functions
$$f(m) = \sqrt{m^2 + 1} + \sqrt{(3-m)^2 + 1}$$
$$\text{and,}\ g(m) = \frac{2(4m^2 - 12m -15}{(m-3)m}$$

The first derivative of $f(m)$ is
$$f^{\prime}(m) = \frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}} + \frac{(m - 3)}{\sqrt{(3 - m)^2 + 1}}$$
Then I solved for $f^{\prime}(m) \gt 0$ since it would tell you what the point of maxima or minima is for the given interval via the first derivative test.

$$f^{\prime}(m) \gt 0$$
$$\implies \frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}} + \frac{(m - 3)}{\sqrt{(3 - m)^2 + 1}} \gt 0$$
$$\implies m\sqrt{(3-m)^2+1} + (m-3)\sqrt{m^2+1} \gt 0$$
$$\implies m\sqrt{(3-m)^2+1} \gt -(m-3)\sqrt{m^2+1}$$
$$\implies m^2 ((3-m)^2+1) \gt (m-3)^2 (m^2+1)$$
$$\implies m^4 - 6m^3 + 10m^2 > m^4 - 6m^3 + 10m^2 - 6m + 9$$
$$\implies m \gt \frac{3}{2}$$

Thus, $m = 1.5$ is a point of local minimum. And $f(0) = \sqrt{10} + 1\approx 4.162\dots$, $f(3) = \sqrt{10} + 1\approx 4.162\dots$, $f(1.5) = 2\sqrt{3.25} \approx 3.605\dots$.

$$\therefore f(m) \in [3.605\dots, 4.162\dots]\ \forall \ m \in [0, 3]$$

And doing the same for $g(m)$, we will get
$$\begin{align}
g^{\prime}(m) &= \frac{2m(m-3)(8m-12) - 2(2m-3)(4m^2 -12m -15)}{(m-3)^2 m^2}\\
&=\frac{(2m-3)\cdot(8m^2 - 24m - 8m^2 + 24m + 30)}{(m-3)^2 m^2}\\
&=\frac{30(2m-3)}{(m-3)^2 m^2}
\end{align}$$

Then solve for $g^{\prime}(m) \gt 0$ to get $m \gt 1.5$, which will be a point of local minimum. If I define a function
$$h(m) = \sqrt{g(m)} - 1$$

Then we will have $h(1.5) = 8/\sqrt{3} - 1 \approx 3.618\dots$, $h(0)$ and $h(3)$ approach positive infinity.

$$\therefore h(m) \in [3.618\dots, \infty] \ \forall \ m \in [0,3]$$

Since $f(m)$ and $h(m)$ never intersect, we can conclude that $f(m) \leq h(m) \ \forall \ m \in [0,3]$.

Comment: "*Since $f(m)$ and $h(m)$ never intersect*" $\;-\;$ If you prove that then all the rest is superfluous, since both are continuous functions which means a strict inequality between the two must hold true throughout. But I don't see the proof of that "*never intersect*" statement.

Comment: @dxiv I admit I did not prove it explicitly. I tried equating the expressions on both sides of the inequality and did not get a real solution, so I concluded that they do not intersect. I shall edit my answer soon when I can.